# Limit pagination with Owl Carousel 2

Tags: jquery, css, carousel, owl-carousel

I have googled this so much there doesn't seem to be an answer our there. I am using Owl Carousel 2. I want to limit the amount of dots that are displayed. So lets say I have ten items. I want to display a dot for every item but I only want to show 5 dots at a time. 
Also if anyone knows how to display a start, end and next x amount button, that would also be very helpful. I am not sure if Owl Carousel has the capability for all of that.

My settings for owl-carousel:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.owl-carousel1').owlCarousel({
    loop:false,
    margin:10,
    center:true,
    autoWidth:false,
    dots:true,
    lazyLoad : true,
    autoHeight : true,
    navigation: true,       
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:1
        },
        1000:{
            items:1
        }
    }

})
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Did anyone get solution for this? I'm stuck with the same issue here with owl carousel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a CSS solution:

```
.owl-pagination {
  .owl-page:nth-child(n+6) {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Change X in nth-child(n+X) to set the maximum number of pages.